# call requires api level 24 (current min is 21) new android.icu.text.DecimalFormat

Tags: android, parse-platform

sorry I'm new how do I call this in a older API or ?
getting this warning call requires api level 24 (current min is 21) new android.icu.text.DecimalFormat

```
public static String roundThousandsIntoK(Number number) {
    char[] suffix = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'};
    long numValue = number.longValue();
    int value = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(numValue));
    int base = value / 3;
    if (value >= 3 && base < suffix.length) {
        return new DecimalFormat("#0.0").format(numValue / Math.pow(10, base * 3)) + suffix[base];
    } else {
        return new DecimalFormat("#,##0").format(numValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `java.text.DecimalFormat` instead of `android.icu.text.DecimalFormat`. Check the `import` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: wow that was fast thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

you should use Decimal Format of java

```
java.text.DecimalFormat
```

please refer more for it http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

Answer (score -3):

To resolve require API level error you can follow this steps :-
1)go to file
2)then select for "Project Structure"
3)then go in module section and click on the "Default configuration"
4)scroll down and click on min SDK version and choose
5)press ok

Comment: Using java decimal format this error doesn't even exist an this case has no benefit on using icu version. Also api warnings like those often require alternative code by using build.version tests. Lowering the SDK version should be done thinking in the target audience and not just to deal with a coding problem.